# How can I enforce one checkbox or another

Tags: custom-field, required-field

We use Salesforce to schedule appointments to help job seekers and require that our program participants allow us to remind them of upcoming appointments via email, text message, or both. `Email_Opt_in__c` and `Text_Opt_in__c` are custom checkbox objects and I need a way to enforce:

- Either `Email_Opt_in__c` is checked
- OR `Text_Opt_in__c` is checked
- OR both are checked when saving participant record

How can I do this on distinct custom fields (in a custom object)?

Comment: any reason why you didnt use a multi select picklist that is required?

Comment: Did you try a validation rule? What have you tried?

Comment: We didn't use multi select picklist because it didn't look as good on the form. Form is also sometimes being filled out by a radio button on an external form app so required is enforced there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [validation rules](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/point_click_business_logic/units/validation_rules), so go through the link since you'll be working with them alot.

IF the validation rule return `false`, then user will be able to save.

So one or both of statements should return `false` so that the validation return `false`, and the user will be able to save.

```
IF (Email_Opt_in__c == TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)  && 
IF (Text_Opt_in__c == TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
```

Comment: This worked great by adding a new Validation Rule to the custom object the fields appeared in (Setup --> Create --> Object --> select custom object --> choose to create new Validation Rule).